# How to expose Chaincode API as REST with Hyperledger go SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode

We have configured hyperledger Fabric 1.2 on Amazon Managed Blockchain network. We have followed 8 steps guide [managed-blockchain-get-started-tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/managed-blockchain/latest/managementguide/managed-blockchain-get-started-tutorial.html) to configure this setup.
We have configured network, member and peer and VPC Service endpoint is also setup. Fabric Client VM is also configured on AWS Linux 2 AMI and we are also able to Install/Initiate and Invoke example chaincode( as mentioned on [Set 7: Install and Run chaincode](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/managed-blockchain/latest/managementguide/get-started-chaincode.html)). 
Now our roadblock is how to expose an API as rest so that the API can be accessed from outside the Fabric client VM. We are struggling from many days.

As per AWS Tutorial (Step 7.4: Invoke the Chaincode) We are invoking the chaincode with below command.

```
docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true" -e "CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/home/managedblockchain-tls-chain.pem"  -e "CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=$PEER"  -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=$MSP"  -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=$MSP_PATH"  cli peer chaincode invoke -C mychannel  -n mycc -c  '{"Args":["invoke","a","b","10"]}'  -o $ORDERER --cafile /opt/home/managedblockchain-tls-chain.pem --tls
```

I tried sending a post request from postman on ($PEER)

> https://nd-NDNDNDNDND.m-MMMMMMMMMM-n-NNNNNNNNNN.managedblockchain.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:30003/mycc

with payload: `{"Args":["invoke","a","b","10"]}`
But got error:
Could not get any response
There was an error connecting to

> nd-NDNDNDNDND.m-MMMMMMMMMM-n-NNNNNNNNNN.managedblockchain.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:30003/mycc

How can we invoke this API with these arguments as REST call from outside this VM.?

By default Hyperledger 1.2 go SDK is installed, Can you advise us how to expose Chaincode API as REST with go SDK?
We know that for enabling the communication between the front-end and the Hyperledger Fabric Layer, one of the way is gRPC calls, but don't know how to configure and use grpc for Go.

Answer (score 4):

From your explanation, it looks like, you have setup hyperledger fabric network correctly. As you are able to install, instantiate and invoke the chaincode through CLI.

So, lets come to your question, Hyperledger Fabric provides us two types of mechanisms for operations that is through CLI and through RPC(using grpc). You may use Hyperledger fabric SDKs (Node SDK, Java SDK, GO SDK etc) that provides the libraries which implements RPC method for Hyperledger network.

So, you can build a web app(Rest/ Soap) in any of the supported languages. Following are links of SDKs:-

[Hyperledger Fabric Node SDK](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-node)

[Hyperledger Fabric Java SDK](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-java)

[Hyperledger Fabric Go SDK](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go)

Following are samples of Hyperledger fabric web apps:-

[Hyperledger Fabric samples](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples)

I will recommend you to go through Balance transfer example.

Comment: thanks Ankit for sending the links, do you have any particular example ( using grpc with GO )?

Answer (score 4):

Invoking function through chaincode can be done through CLI or using SDKs.

I followed this [chainhero tutorial](https://chainhero.io/2018/03/tutorial-build-blockchain-app-2/) for writing SDK in Golang.

REST APIs were not exposed in this tutorial. For generating REST APIs, I used [gorilla/mux](https://github.com/gorilla/mux) in one of my project. Gorilla/mux is used at the bottom part of the code below:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/chainHero/heroes-service/blockchain"
    "net/http"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "os"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    // Definition of the Fabric SDK properties
    fSetup := blockchain.FabricSetup{
        // Network parameters
        OrdererID: "orderer.hf.chainhero.io",

        // Channel parameters
        ChannelID:     "chainhero",
        ChannelConfig: os.Getenv("GOPATH") + "/src/github.com/chainHero/heroes-service/fixtures/artifacts/chainhero.channel.tx",

        // Chaincode parameters
        ChainCodeID:     "heroes-service",
        ChaincodeGoPath: os.Getenv("GOPATH"),
        ChaincodePath:   "github.com/chainHero/heroes-service/chaincode/",
        OrgAdmin:        "Admin",
        OrgName:         "org1",
        ConfigFile:      "config.yaml",

        // User parameters
        UserName: "User1",
    }

    // Initialization of the Fabric SDK from the previously set properties
    err := fSetup.Initialize()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Unable to initialize the Fabric SDK: %v\n", err)
        return
    }
    // Close SDK
    defer fSetup.CloseSDK()

    // Install and instantiate the chaincode
    err = fSetup.InstallAndInstantiateCC()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Unable to install and instantiate the chaincode: %v\n", err)
        return
    }

    router := mux.NewRouter()

    //GetPerson and CreatePerson are the functions implemented in the chaincode.

    router.HandleFunc("/api/{fcn}",fSetup.GetPerson).Methods("GET")
    router.HandleFunc("/api/{fcn}", fSetup.CreatePerson).Methods("POST")

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8000", router))

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Gorilla mux](https://github.com/gorilla/mux) to expose chaincode api as rest using fabric go sdk.